# LibreOffice AutoRecovery info lost when losing power?

Tags: libreoffice

I had my laptop spinning accidentally until the laptop died.

I have the "Save AutoRecovery information every" checked and set to 15 minutes (default?).

However, when the Recovery took place none of the edits (after last save) that I made yesterday went into the recovered document.

Is there some logs that I can check to see what has actually happened here?

Since this is a misbehaviour on when losing power to a machine, maybe there's a bug already tracking this?

Comment: Did you check `/home/<user_name>/.libreoffice/X/<user_name>/backup` Replace X with your Libreoffice version.

Comment: I don't have a directory named **.libreoffice** in my home directory. Should it be there by default?

Comment: Its hidden make sure that you're viewing hidden files.

Comment: Using the command line doing: `ls -Fla ~/.l*`  
  
Not there..

Comment: Sorry, its `/home/<user_name>/.config/libreoffice/X/user/backup` Replace X with your Libreoffice version.

Comment: The file I found there is identical to the one recovered, i.e. without the changes I made yesterday :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but recovery might only work for any unsaved work.

The 'I had my laptop spinning accidentally until the laptop died.' is not very descriptive.

Comment: I believe the statement was clear about that the edits that I did were not saved.

Well, in Windows you'd typically go into sleep mode at some point when battery is low, but no such functionality kicks in when I am on my Ubuntu laptop.

I cannot choose Hibernate in the power settings for "When power goes critically low" in the system settings.

Comment: It should suspend by default - but that is probably dependent on your Desktop Enviroment e.g. GNOME, KDE...

Comment: Try checking your power settings about what it does when it battery power is low.

Comment: The only option that I can choose for "When power is critically low" is the "Power off" - "Hibernate" is grayed out, which seems to be a Unity thing disabling it by default for all users...   
   
What I really want with this post is to find out:   
1. How can I troubleshoot?   
2. Can LibreOffice gracefully handle if power is lost and no graceful shutdown has been made?   
E.g. take **emacs** where you have the recovery at your fingertips in the #<filename># file/buffer shadowing your <filename> file up to the last char you edited basically.